# Read and move a file so that only one user can access that file

Tags: php

I have a folder called 'BinFolder' which has 6 files

1. file1
2. file2
3. file3
4. file4
5. file5
6. file6

When 2 users need random files at the same time eg

- User 1 wants a file(say file1)
- User 2 wants a file(say file5 , but not file1)

How can I get this with fileread..php avoiding file repetition?

```
    <script>
var button = document.getElementById('test');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {

  <?php

$path    = 'hdcp';
$files = scandir($path);
$files = array_diff(scandir($path), array('.', '..'));
$files = array_diff(scandir($path), array('.', '..'));
$rand = $files[array_rand($files)];
 
?>

 document.getElementById('log2').innerHTML += "<?php echo $rand ;?><br/>" ;

  fetch('hdcp/<?php echo $rand ;?>')
                  .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
                  .then(data => {
                    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(data); 
        
             console.log(byteArray);

            })

</script>
```

Comment: you can use `flock()` function to lock and release a file.

Comment: @behzadmsalehi Same file can be locked by 2 users at the same time?

Comment: in question, you say that user 2 wants a file, but not the file that user 1 get before,  do your need to share 1 file between 2 users? the question needs some clarity.

Comment: @behzadmsalehi Yeah , User1 and User2 need random files. Suppose,at the same time ,user1 and user2 read  file5  (both read same file) as a random file.Now user 1 reads and locks the file , at the same time user2 also reads the same file and locks it, because there is no delay.Is it possible???

Comment: it is possible that 2 requests open a single file simultaneously, but if you need to avoid file repetition (or conflict) you must handle the scenario with some logic.

Comment: @behzadmsalehi Thanks for your reply sir....So flock() would not be helpful in this case.I think node.js can do this . But I don't want to go with node.js.Any other possible solution with php????

Comment: if you want to use node.js for purposes just like the PROMIS concept (to implement the logic), yes you can do such things in PHP too. if this is what you want I can answer the question.

Comment: @behzadmsalehi Yeah ...Promise concept.. For two simultaneous users ,one user should  wait until the other user completes a request.How is it possible in php?

Answer (score 0):

OK, So you can achieve your desired behavior by implementing promise in PHP, as probably you know, PHP is a single tread application that does not have a promise by default (have 1 memory heap and 1 call stack). but if you want to do such behavior, there are some libraries that you can use :

if you are using `PHP >= 8.1` :
you can use [fiber](https://betterprogramming.pub/a-look-at-the-new-php-8-1-fibers-feature-979489399918)
if you are using `PHP <8.1` :
you can use [reactphp](https://reactphp.org/)

those are two high star/recommended libraries for implementing "promise" in PHP.
as you say yourself in the comment :

> For two simultaneous users, one user should wait until the other user completes a request

and it's exactly what you should do in case of your requirement.

***react PHP is a low-level library that has an event loop in its core so that it makes it possible to run codes async.***

for more explanation, I can say that a promise is an object that establishes a relationship between Producing Code and Consuming Code :

Producing Code: some codes that require some time to run.
Consuming Code: some codes that wait for the result of producing code.

first of all, for installing ReactPHP you must add it to your project by the composer :

```
composer require react/promise
```

now you must to create an promise object:

```
use React/Promise/Promise;
$promise = new Promise($resolver, $canceller)
```

you can set $resolver and $canceller as bellow :

**resolver**

```
$resolver = function (callable $resolve, callable $reject) {
// Do some work, possibly asynchronously, and then
// resolve or reject.

$resolve('Promise is resolved');
// or throw new Exception('Promise rejected');
// or $resolve($anotherPromise);
// or $reject($nastyError);
};
```

**canceller**

```
$canceller = function () {
// Cancel/abort any running operations like network connections, streams etc.
// Reject promise by throwing an exception
throw new Exception('Promise cancelled');
};
```

and in the end for using them you can write such a scripts like :

```
$promise->then( 
    fn($value) => echo '$value' ; 
    fn($value) => echo '$value' ;
```

the first closure will be run in the case of running promise successfully and the second one will be run if the promise rejects.

Comment: Thank you for your help...I hope reactphp can help me .But I don't get more about reactphp in internet.Now i have edited my code and added my code..Please help me how I can implement reactPhp with it.....

Comment: sure, I have been edited the answer for helping you. if you need more information you can read more here: https://githubhelp.com/reactphp/promise